# How's 504 response header handled in ajax request in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, nginx

I have an ajax call from client, that looks like that:

```
$.ajax({
            'url': '/converter/ajax-make-corrections/',
            'data': {

                corrections: JSON.stringify(globalCorrrectionsObject)
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {

            }
        })
```

This action send pretty big file to server to do some server job. The trouble is that there is timelimit on server - 30 minutes. After that server closes a connection with 504 errror (here is what I see in nginx access log file):

```
[06/May/2015:09:13:33 +0300] "POST /converter/ajax-make-corrections/ HTTP/1.1" 504
```

and at the same tim in nginx error.log file

```
*1799741 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client:
```

There is no errors in apache log.

And here is what happened: action from browser was restarted 9 times exactly 30 minutes after each other. Since action in browser can not be start manually second time with same data, my best guess is that $.ajax action was restarting itself after getting 504 response. Is it possible? How $.ajax handles 504 response? Will it restart itself sending same data again?

Comment: can you take a look at network tab in inspector to see if the ajax call did restarted? ajax call is only fireing once, not multiple times, check your page to see if something is triggering it to fire 9x ??

Comment: Have to tried to increase execution time?

Answer (score 1):

> $.ajax action was restarting itself after getting 504 response. Is it possible? Will it restart itself sending same data again?

In this particular case, I would say **no**. There is nothing in the script you provided that makes it possible to make a request.

> How $.ajax handles 504 response?

```
error: function (request, status, error) {
    alert(request.responseText);
}
```

Also try to increase [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600); //1 hour
```